# Using \input vs. \scantokens in section title (with package hyperref)

Tags: hyperref, tex-core, expansion

I meet the following issue when trying to use `\scantokens` in section titles, together with the `hyperref` package (whithout this package, all is fine).

`\protect\input...` can appear in a section title. But the same construction with `\scantokens` instead fails ("Second"): it appears that hyperref does not care about protection when creating a pdf string. Using `\unexpanded{\protect\scantokens{...}}` prevent expansion ("Fifth"), but if we leave out `\protect`, it crashes again ("Third"). Using two `\unexpanded` also works ("Fourth").

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{\protect\input{data}}
% \section{\protect\scantokens{Second}}
% \section{\unexpanded{\scantokens{Third}}}
\section{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{\scantokens{Fourth}}}}
\section{\unexpanded{\protect\scantokens{Fifth}}}
\end{document}
```

(The file `data` only contains `First` (or whatever).) The example above compiles, but removing one of the `%` will make it fail.

> Why do we need two levels of unexpansion/protection? Is there a neater way to do this?

Context: I have written a package (cprotect.dtx) that allows verbatim in the argument of most commands, by writing the argument to a file and `\input`ting it. Now, it would be nicer to use `\scantokens` rather than writing dozens of auxiliary files.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `\jobname.toc` and `\jobname.out` files? (Note that the latter is used for PDF Outline stuff, so if you aren't trying to make a PDF it probably won't exist...)

Comment: @SamB: I think I partially tracked down the problem: `\pdfstringdef` expands its argument, but does not set `\protect` to `\noexpand\protect\noexpand` as most other LaTeX cases of expanded definitions. To see this, we can run TeX on the minimal example  --- `\documentclass{article}    \usepackage{hyperref}    \begin{document}    \def\AAA{\show\BBB}   \pdfstringdef{\foo}{\protect \AAA}    \end{document}` --- Note that the error is `\BBB` not defined, meaning that `\show` was expanded and not executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My other answer was the wrong approach. It can't work, because it is essentially impossible to delay expansion across a `\pdfstringdef`.

Instead, what we have to do is to stop [e-]TeX from signaling a `Runaway definition` / `! File ended while scanning definition ...` at the end the `\scantokens`; which it does because `\scantokens` considers the generated tokens to come from a file named " ", and the string argument to `\pdfstringdef` ends up in the "replacement text" for an `\xdef` (cleverly disguised as a `\Hy@temp`), as seen in the following excerpt from `\pdfstringdef` (see [`hyperref.dtx`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/hyperref.dtx) / [`hyperref.pdf`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/hyperref.pdf) for the full source):

```
      \let\Hy@temp\xdef
      \let\def\HyPsd@DefCommand
      \let\gdef\HyPsd@DefCommand
      \let\edef\HyPsd@DefCommand
      \let\xdef\HyPsd@DefCommand
      \let\futurelet\HyPsd@LetCommand
      \let\let\HyPsd@LetCommand
      \Hy@temp#1{#2}%
```

(Evidently, it never occurred to Knuth that someone might want to read in a file during the expansion of`\edef`/`\xdef`; I didn't even find this exact error message in the index to "TeX: The Program"!)

I thought this was going to be a lot trickier, but [they tell me](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9826/how-to-do-scantokens-inside-edef-without-triggering-runaway-definition/9829#9829) it's simply a matter of inserting a `\noexpand` before the right brace in the parameter to `\scantokens`, and they seem to be right. For example, the following generates a PDF with a working outline without triggering any warnings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{\scantokens{Test\noexpand}}

\end{document}
```

#### Caveat

Unfortunately this might not help you very much if you need `\catcode` reassignments, since those are *stomach* commands, and the stomach is not available in `\pdfstringdef`.

If that turns out to be a problem, you might try using `\detokenize` instead, since that is hard-coded to produce character tokens of categories 12 (for most characters) and 10 (for character 32, the ASCII space character) -- I couldn't help but notice this in the [e-TeX manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/e-tex/v2/doc/etex_man.pdf) (see page 14) when I was scouring it for a way to avoid the "Runaway definition" issue.

Comment: Thank you. In my case, `\cprotect\section{...}` reads the argument of `\section` before feeding it to it with the correct catcodes (this allows verbatim in the argument). Currently, I write to a file, and input it. This requires many auxiliary files (one per `\cprotect`). I am trying to use `\scantokens` instead. All this is to say that no, I don't need catcode assignments, and I can put `\noexpand` at the end of the file/scantokened piece. There are other issues, though (table of contents), that will require one well structured auxiliary file. More work than I want to do right now.

Comment: @Bruno—I think, but I might be wrong, that `\everyeof={\noexpand}` would be a better idea that appending the `\noexpand` manually.

Comment: @Will: doing `\everyeof={\noexpand}` locally is not an option, because I need to use `\scantokens` in an expansion context (e.g., `\pdfstring`). And I'm afraid that doing it globally might screw up other packages/user `\input` (?). Also, I already had to append a control word to gobble the extra new line at the end of the file (`\scantokens{a}b` gives `a b`), so changing it to `\noexpand` is easy (of course, I am playing around with non-printable characters to be robust against (most) catcode changes).

Comment: @Bruno—Sounds sensible. I'm pretty sure you can fix the extra newline problem with `\endlinechar=-1` while `\scantokens` is operating (as done in the expl3 implementation).

Comment: @Will: I had not tried that, and I think that it would work. But I need expandability.

Comment: @Bruno: well, surely you *could* append `\noexpand` to `\everyeof` locally to the `\cprotect` -- which is not to say, by any means, that this wouldn't cause just as much trouble for other packages if they happened to be used in the protected text; merely that the "stomach" would have to be available at that time, since you wouldn't be able to mess with `\catcode` otherwise...

Comment: @SamB: it seems cleaner to append `^^E^^L`, where `^^E` is given catcode escape, and `^^L` letter, and define `\^^L` to be `\noexpand`: that gobbles the space, and  takes care of the end-of-file. As long as I work with files, there is still a risk that `\catcode\`^` gets changed, but with scantokens, it should work. --- I might end up using http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9781/are-we-inside-an-edef to fall back towards a detokenized version in an expanding context, and to the right `\scantokens` in a non-expanding context.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the following: it won't help; \pdfstringdef will strip any unrecognized control sequences from the expansion -- we MUST expand at that time. Now all we've got to do is figure out why that doesn't work already...

<strike>I would suggest adding the appropriate redefinition of `\protect` to the `\pdfstringdefPreHook` hook with [`\pdfstringdefDisableCommands`](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html#x1-160004.1.2). Probably this would go something like the following:</strike>

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\protect{\noexpand\protect\noexpand}%
}
```

Comment: (`\{` -> `{`) --- Your solution unfortunately prints hyperref's warnings in the pdf file: `\documentclass{article}    \usepackage{hyperref}    \begin{document}    \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\protect{\noexpand\protect\noexpand}}    \section{Test}    \end{document}`

Comment: @Bruno: Okay, yeah, this is a dead end -- it's not going to work with the approach employed by `\pdfstringdef`.

Comment: what worries me is that I am using that for a general purpose package, where I can't easily have a special case for "sections using hyperref". The best is probably to stick with `\input`, or use plenty of `\unexpanded` and `\protect`. But is there a bound on the number that would be needed?

Comment: @Bruno: that really can't work; any unrecognized control sequences will be discarded before the string is written to the `.out` file. It must be arranged that your user-level macros be expandable during a `\pdfstringdef`. I still don't understand why `\scantokens` inside a section heading is screwing up the .aux... but maybe if we arrange for \protect to be used except in \pdfstringdef, it will work?

Comment: **Note:** I'm leaving this answer here, despite its being a dead-end, because I think it could be instructive for others to see *why* it is a dead end. (For posterity: my [other answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9183/using-input-vs-scantokens-in-section-title-with-package-hyperref/9870#9870) explains why `\scantokens` was failing.)