# Are we inside an edef?

Tags: tex-core, expansion, e-tex

How would you test whether we are in an expansion only context (i.e., `\edef`, `\xdef`, `\write`,...) or not? The only ways I could think of leave things behind (but the full expansion of that extra stuff is empty).

Is there a clean way of testing this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\expiffalse{\expandafter\iffalse}
\protected\def\mygobble#1{\ifx\iftrue#1\expiffalse\fi}
\def\ifexpanding{\mygobble\iftrue\relax}

\begin{document}
We test that it sort of works: first, we are
\ifexpanding expanding\else not expanding\fi. 

Then, we are%
\edef\foo{\ifexpanding expanding\else not expanding\fi}
\show\foo
\foo.
\end{document}
```

Comment: FWIW, my take on this was along the lines of `\let\voodoo\voodoo` with `\voodoo` starting with \relax\relax and ignoring its first argument, which does pretty much the same thing, but would leave a \let\relax\relax in an expanding context. (The whole story can be found in nag.dtx. Ah, the days we were young...)

Comment: @Ulrich: that's simpler than what I had! Although it has the same drawbacks, and in my case we obtain a protected but expandable command (if that makes sense).

Comment: @Bruno: yes, you're right. I admit to not having the required zen state to understand your solution right now. ;)

Comment: I'm curious, when would this come up?

Comment: @TH.: I am writing a package that reads a LaTeX source, and does TeXish macro replacements before rewriting itself to another file. For this, I replace each character by a macro, which should have two different behaviours depending on the expansion context. If it is running text in the source (i.e., typesetting, non-expanding), it should write the corresponding character to the output. If it is already in a `\write`, it should simply expand to the character. --- Since I have full control on what is going on, I can just keep track of things with a boolean, but I was lead to the question above.

Comment: With your input I get "somethinglink", also if I add an optional argument, so `\test` *is* expanded.

Comment: @egreg: Botheration.  You're right.  That particular behaviour was coming from my custom driver ... I'll have to investigate that a little closer to see what was going on there.  (I think that the actual question is independent of that particular motivation, isn't it?)

Comment: Okay, so that *specific* case was due to a misuse (and misunderstanding) of `\Hy@WrapperDef`.

Comment: @egreg: I've edited to remove that example.  Thanks for the help on that.

Comment: (I've flagged for a moderator to merge them.)

Comment: Nobody has found a general solution in these 12 years (without leaving extra tokens)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe not, hence the addition of `\ifincsname` in pdfTeX (and XeTeX, I think). This came out of discussions way back when on detecting/testing all of the different expansion contexts, but IIRC the csname expansion was the only one that was easy or maybe unambiguous to implement.

Er, sorry for the vague answer; I'll pull up some references if they come to me.

Comment: Thanks. I'll leave the question open for a bit more, but I'm afraid that your answer is the right one. Although it is not clear why pdftex couldn't have a primitive for testing "if a protected sequence would expand there or not".

Answer (score 8):

Short answer: no. Longer answer: To detect this would require a primitive which 'knows' about expansion. However, writing one is non-trivial: see the issues surrounding `\ifincsname` for demonstrations of why detection of this sort of thing is hard.

If you look at the LaTeX kernel, the `\protect` mechanism is about expansion. To work, it all has to be set up with `\protect` redefined correctly. That's why LaTeX2e 'robust' commands still require `\protected@edef` and similar to be used: within an `\edef` it is too late to alter anything.

Answer (score 7):

Yes and no. My usual trick for this is this:

```
\def\voodoo#1#2{\relax\relax\Expansionstuff}
[...]
\let\voodoo\voodoo\Realstuff
```

if I haven't gotten it wrong: in an expanding context, 
`\let\voodoo\voodoo\RealStuff` expands left-to-right to
`\let\relax\relax\Expansionstuff`, continuing to expand `\Expansionstuff` since `\let` and `\relax` are primitive, but in either case, 
you are left with a reasonably non-harmful `\let\x\x` thingy.

Comment: So that's all *inside* the real macro, is that right?

Comment: However, this leaves your `\edef` or `\write` result containing extra tokens.

Comment: @Andrew: No, the `\voodoo` needs to be prepared in advance.

Comment: Okay, I'm having trouble seeing how it all fits together, but I haven't played with it yet.  I'll have a go at trying it out and will get back to you.

Comment: @Andrew: Define `\newcommand{\@ifexpanding}{\let\@ifexpanding@\@ifexpanding@\@secondoftwo}` and `\newcommand{\@ifexpanding@}[4]{\relax\relax#3}`. You can then use it in macros as `\@ifexpanding{<expandable code>}{<non-expandable code>}`.