# Can I detect (from within a macro) if I'm in an \edef (or similar)?

Tags: macros, expansion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are we inside an edef?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9781/are-we-inside-an-edef)

I've defined a macro that changes its behaviour depending on the next character, so it uses `\@ifnextchar`.  This makes it behave badly inside things like `\edef`s.  I'd like to define a "failsafe" behaviour, something like:

```
\ifExpansionOnly
  \doSomethingSensibleButSafe
\else
  \doTheRealThing
\fi
```

Is that possible to detect?  It feels like something to do with "fragile" and "robust" commands, but my experimental skills are failing me here.

(**Edit:** removed motivation from using `hyperref`; turned out the behaviour that I was seeing there was due to using `\Hy@WrapperDef` in the wrong place.)

Comment: Duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9781/2707?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Yes, that looks like a duplicate to me.  (And Ulrich ought to have noticed that!)  I'd say that this was actually a case for a *merge* since Ulrich's answered this one but only left a comment on yours.