# How to test if a macro is being expanded between \csname ... \endcsname, in (e-)upTeX?

Tags: macros, expansion, primitives

pdfTeX added some new primitives, based on e-TeX, including `\ifincsname`. When this primitive is being expanded between a pair of `\csname ... \endcsname`, the result of expansion will be `true`, otherwise `false` will be the result.

As the successor of pdfTeX, LuaTeX conserves `\ifincsname` as its primitive; in terms of XeTeX, it implements the `\ifincsname` primitive, too. However, in (e-)upTeX (and also ApTeX), there is not a primitive named or equalling to pdfTeX's `\ifincsname`.

Hence, here is the question: how to implement a macro to define if a macro is being expanded between `\csname ...\endcsname`, in (e-)upTeX.

Comment: 'You can't': note that `\ifincsname` is a tricky thing at best - nesting can be a real issue.

Comment: BTW, I don't know ApTeX: could you include (or comment) a link?

Comment: @JosephWright ApTeX is short for Asiatic pTeX. The former name of it is pTeX-ng, which you might have idea about.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for the final answer, though it kills the question. `: (`

Comment: Successor? I don't regard LuaLaTeX etc. as a successor to PdfTeX etc

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I get the successor statement from http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-whatpdftex.html and http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-luatex.html, as `pdfTeX` is frozen and future development is focused on `LuaTeX`.

Comment: Somewhat related, [tex core - Are we inside an edef? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9781/are-we-inside-an-edef/9783#9783)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

There is no way from TeX90/e-TeX primitives to tell that expansion is happening inside a `\csname`.  One might imagine setting some flag, and replacing the 'real' `\csname` by a macro, but that would break expandability.

It's worth noting that `\ifincsname` is tricky to get right: there are various awkward edge case situations (for example nesting in `\ifcsname`) that make it a hard primitive to get right.