# How to do \scantokens inside \edef without triggering "Runaway definition"

Tags: tex-core, expansion, e-tex

I'm trying to find a way to use the e-TeX `\scantokens` command inside [the equivalent of] an `\edef` (well, actually an `\xdef`, but presumably this does not make any real difference since that's just the `\global` version of `\edef`). The reason I am doing this is that it seems to be needed to answer [this question about hyperref and pdf outlines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9183/using-input-vs-scantokens-in-section-title-with-package-hyperref).

The problem seems to be that `\scantokens` doesn't actually expand to the tokens scanned; it actually expands to nothing, but arranges for the next tokens to be read from a pseudo-file named " ", which is then treated almost exactly like a real file, including the check for "runaway" conditions. (See page 10 of [the e-TeX manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/e-tex/v2/doc/etex_man.pdf).)

There is one problem with this explanation, though: why would [`\input` work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9183/using-input-vs-scantokens-in-section-title-with-package-hyperref), as it evidently does in the other question?

Anyway, here's a fairly minimal example:

```
%&eplain

% make \scantokens pseudo-files show up with name " " in the output
\tracingscantokens=1

\edef\foo{\scantokens{Test}}
```

Which produces the output

```
Running `TeX' on `scantokens-in-edef-minimal' with ``pdftex  -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" "scantokens-in-edef-minimal"''
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(e:\home\tex\scantokens-in-edef-minimal.tex ( )
Runaway definition?
->Test 
! File ended while scanning definition of \foo.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.6 \edef\foo{\scantokens{Test}
                               }
! Too many }'s.
l.6 \edef\foo{\scantokens{Test}}

)
! Emergency stop.
<*> \input scantokens-in-edef-minimal

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on scantokens-in-edef-minimal.log.

TeX exited abnormally with code 1 at Thu Jan 27 12:24:57
```

Is it perhaps possible to somehow do the expansion with macros and then do a `\def` instead of the `\edef`, so the expansion would be finished before the definition began, and the "runaway definition" condition avoided?

Comment: The same question, asking on the opposite direction: [input - Why is \everyeof{\noexpand} needed to avoid "File ended while scanning definition of" with expandable read from file? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516031/why-is-everyeof-noexpand-needed-to-avoid-file-ended-while-scanning-definitio)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In short, yes. Try

```
\edef\foo{\scantokens{Test\noexpand}}
```

or

```
\everyeof={\noexpand}
\edef\foo{\scantokens{text}}
```

in which the `\noexpand` ‘hides’ the EOF marker by turning it into `\relax`.

You might like to take a look at the definition of expl3's `\tl_rescan:nn` and `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn`, both wrappers for `\scantokens` based on the ideas in Heiko Oberdiek's `catchfile` package.

Then you can write

```
\tl_set_rescan:Nnn \foo { «catcode setup» } { «rescanned tokens» }
```

or

```
\tl_rescan:nn { «catcode setup» } { «tokens to re-scan (in a group)» }
```

The latter cannot be used inside an `\edef` but can otherwise come in handy when you're processing a macro argument that has already been tokenised. In practise I find the `set_rescan` version a little more convenient.

Comment: And if you were using luatex, you could use `\scantextokens` instead of the `\everyeof` hack.

Comment: @Taco—Indeed! Sorry I omitted it `:)`

Comment: Cool; I'll relay this answer back to the asker of the other question. I was afraid it would be necessary to essentially implement `\edef`/`\xdef` from scratch!

Comment: Now if only I could understand *how* making the `}` act like `\relax` would fool e-TeX into finishing the `\scantokens` without doing the runaway checks, then I'd ... well, I guess I might just have a headache, actually :-).

Comment: * Pulls up `source2e.pdf` to find out what LaTeX does to `\input` that prevents this from happening... *

Comment: @SamB—it's not the `}` that is affected by the `\noexpand` but the invisible end-of-file marker inserted by `\scantokens`.

Comment: @Will: Where can I read about this marker? It's obviously not going to be in [Volume B](http://www.amazon.com/Computers-Typesetting-B-TeX-Program/dp/0201134373), and MiKTeX doesn't seem to have a working "weave" (though I guess I could weave it on my Debian box if worst came to worst)...

Comment: @SamB—Perhaps this thread may be instructive: https://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/854391a7654a467d/6825ae391f0a7bab