# Insert `\hfill` after each character

Tags: macros

I am creating a title page as follows:

```
\begin{titlepage}
  \vspace*{1in}
  \begin{center}
    \parbox{0.8\textwidth}[s]{\HUGE%
      T\hfill H\hfill I\hfill S\hfill 
      \hfill\hfill\hfill\hfill %space = 4xhfill
      I\hfill S %no hfill after the last character of the line.
    }\\
    \parbox{0.8\textwidth}[s]{\HUGE%
      M\hfill Y\hfill
      \hfill\hfill\hfill\hfill
      T\hfill I\hfill T\hfill L\hfill E
    }\\
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \vspace*{1in}
\end{titlepage}
```

`\HUGE` is defined as follows: `\def\HUGE{\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont}`.

I would like to replace the many `X\hfill` with an automated macro that inserts `\hfill` after each character automatically and replaces any whitespace with four `\hfill`, *i.e.* a macro that would allow me to write:

```
...
\begin{center}
  \titleline{0.8\titlewidth}{THIS IS}\\
  \titleline{0.8\titlewidth}{MY TITLE}\\
\end{center}
...
```

I am using (Xe)LaTeX and would like to make that macro in a package that would work on both systems, on classes such as `article` and `book`. I have no experience with other document classes.

Thank you.

Comment: take a look at the `soul` package (`texdoc soul` -- it's in tex live).  this can be used to provide letterspacing and a lot more besides.  comment on your code: multiple `\hfill`s in one line can result in some serious warnings.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: `soul` doesn't provide me with what I want; however, it is a nice addition to packages that I *may* find useful in the future. Also, I wasn't aware of any consequences at using multiple `\hfill`s.

Comment: Rather than using `\hfill` I'd suggest to give a look at the letter spacing features of `microtype`. I'd add that looking for a macro based solution that automatically inserts spaces is too much, for a title that won't have much more than 20 characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't particularly care for the output, but the following does more or less exactly what you wanted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% The user-facing command
\newcommand\titleline[2][0.8\linewidth]{%
    {\Huge\parbox{#1}{\addhfills{#2}}\\}%
}

\makeatletter
\def\addhfills#1{%
    % rescan the argument with catcode 12 for spaces (so that they aren't ignored).
    \begingroup\catcode` =12\relax\xdef\tmp{\scantokens{#1\noexpand}}\endgroup%
    \expandafter\addhfills@@\tmp\addhfills@end%
}
% save catcode 12 space
\begingroup\catcode` =12\relax\gdef\otherspace{ }\endgroup
% an end marker
\def\addhfills@end{\relax}

\def\addhfills@@#1{#1\addhfills@@@}
\def\addhfills@@@#1{%
    \ifx#1\addhfills@end\else%
        \def\tmp{#1}%
        \ifx\tmp\otherspace%
            \hfill\hfill%
        \else%
            \hfill#1%
        \fi%
        \expandafter\addhfills@@@%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \titleline{THIS IS}
  \titleline{MY TITLE}
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: May I ask what the `\noexpand` is for?

Comment: @RyanReich: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9826/how-to-do-scantokens-inside-edef-without-triggering-runaway-definition

Answer (score 10):

Here's a `microtype` based solution. I've used `\Huge`, but the principle is the same:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\centering
\parbox{.8\textwidth}{\Huge
\parfillskip=0pt
\hrule
\medskip
\textls[200]{THIS IS MY TITLE}

\medskip
\hrule}
\end{document}
```

One of the keys is to set `\parfillskip` to zero, so TeX won't add any space to fill the paragraph's last line. You can adjust the optional argument to `\textls` until the result is satisfying; I believe that *no* automated solution can substitute your eye.

[image: example]

Answer (score 8):

Here's an option using a regular `\makebox`. The optional alignment specification `s` spreads out its contents to fit within the given box width. Here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\centering
\rule{.5\linewidth}{1pt} \par
\makebox[.5\linewidth][c]{THIS IS MY TITLE} \par
\makebox[.5\linewidth][s]{T H I S {} I S {} M Y {} T I T L E} \par
\makebox[.5\linewidth][s]{T H I S {} {} I S {} {} M Y {} {} T I T L E} \par
\rule{.5\linewidth}{1pt}
\end{document}
```

Adding `{}` increases the space allowed for interword spaces.

Answer (score 6):

A solution using `tikz` and `text along path` decoration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\def\HUGE{\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont}
\newlength{\heighttitle}%
\newlength{\depthtitle}%
\newcommand\bigtitle[2][\linewidth]{%
 \noindent\HUGE\centering%
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \path%
   [postaction={decoration={text along path, text={|\HUGE|#2},
       text align=fit to path}, decorate}]
   (0,0) -- (#1,0);
   \begin{pgfinterruptpicture}%
     \setlength{\heighttitle}{\heightof{\HUGE #2}}%
     \global\heighttitle=\heighttitle
     \setlength{\depthtitle}{\depthof{\HUGE #2}}%
     \global\depthtitle=\depthtitle
   \end{pgfinterruptpicture}%
   \coordinate (h) at (0pt,\heighttitle);
   \coordinate (d) at (0pt,-\depthtitle);
   \path[use as bounding box]
   (current bounding box.west |- d)
   rectangle
   (current bounding box.east |- h);
 \end{tikzpicture}\par%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \bigtitle[.8\linewidth]{THIS IS}
  \bigtitle[.8\linewidth]{MY TITLE}
  \vfill
  \bigtitle[\linewidth]{THIS IS}
  \bigtitle[\linewidth]{MY TITLE}
\end{titlepage}
\begin{titlepage}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: TeX.SX rule 34: No matter what the problem is, someone will post a TikZ-based solution. ;)

Comment: @Caramdir: ;) It's not a perfect solution (right vertical alignment are not perfect). A solution without TikZ is obviously possible (desirable?) but I don't know how to split a string...

Comment: @Caramdir: I found a way to split a string: `xstring`. See my other answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution using `xstring` and `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\def\HUGE{\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont}
\newcommand\bigtitle[2][\linewidth]{%
  {\def\result{\HUGE}%
  \StrSplit{#2}{1}{\firstchar}{\rest}%
  \eappto\result{\firstchar}%
  \IfStrEq{\rest}{}{}{\restbigtitle{\rest}}%
  \noindent\HUGE\centering
  \makebox[#1]{\result}\par}

}
\newcommand\restbigtitle[1]{%
  \StrSplit{#1}{1}{\firstchar}{\rest}%
  \IfStrEq{\firstchar}{ }{%
    \eappto\result{\hfill\hfill\hfill}%
  }{%
    \eappto\result{\hfill\firstchar}%
  }%
  \IfStrEq{\rest}{}{}{\restbigtitle{\rest}}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \null
  \vfill
  \bigtitle{THIS IS}
  \bigtitle{MY TITLE}
  \vfill
  \bigtitle[.8\linewidth]{THIS IS}
  \bigtitle[.8\linewidth]{MY TITLE}
  \vfill
  \bigtitle{THIS IS MY}
  \bigtitle{TITLE}
  \vfill
  \null
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** I use `makebox` instead of `minipage` to allow warning about `overfull \hbox` if text is too large.

Answer (score 4):

I remember an answer from egreg to one of my questions and it may be a possibility.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mytitle}{m}
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 } { ##1 \hfill }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
  \Huge
    \mytitle{{THIS}  {IS} \\ {MY} {TITLE}\\}  
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]