# practical use of `\noexpand` outside`\edef`(`\xdef`) and `\write`(`\messge`)?

Tags: expansion, plain-tex

After reading (and searching through) `TeXbyTopic.pdf` I have the impression that practical use of `\noexpand` falls into one of the following three cases,

1. Inside `\edef` or `\xdef`, including the cases where macros are defined so that they are used in the context of `\edef`, such as

   `\def\protect{\noexpand\protect\noexpand}`
2. Inside `\write` and `\message`, including the case of movable texts in LaTeX
3. In the special construction `\if\noexpand#1\relax`

Are there any other practical uses of `\noexpand`? Are there any practical use of `\noexpand` that is not in the expansion-only context, except for #3 listed above? I am new to plain and hope to understand plain better (especailly, the expansion-only context) by understanding various usages of `\noexpand`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of tex primitives that expand tokens looking for arguments like `\if` and `\ifcat`. `\noexpand` would have a similar effect with any of them but whether or not that is *useful* is harder to say.

for example

```
\def\zz{hello}

\input s\noexpand\zz

\bye
```

inputs the file `s.tex` and then typesets `hello` whereas

```
\def\zz{hello}

\input s\zz

\bye
```

produces

```
! I can't find file `shello'.
```

But you could more easily have used a space after `s` than `\noexpand` to stop the scan for a filename.

As indicated by Henri in comments there is also the use to nullify the end of file token in input or `\scantokens`

```
\edef\zz{\scantokens{z}}
```

is the error

```
! File ended while scanning definition of \zz.
```

but

```
\edef\zz{\scantokens{z\noexpand}}
```

or

```
\everyeof{\noexpand}
\edef\zz{\scantokens{z}}
```

are error free.

Comment: I think this one may be useful under some cases. Glad to learn about it.

Comment: `a\scantokens{b}c` vs. `a\scantokens{b\noexpand}c`

Comment: Related: [How to do scantokens inside edef without triggering runaway definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9826/how-to-do-scantokens-inside-edef-without-triggering-runaway-definition). The link can be added to the answer if you wish.

Comment: You can use `\noexpand` for tricking TeX's reading apparatus into state S when having things re-tokenized by `\scantokens` and thus prevent the coming into being of a trailing space token. This is what is shown in the comment of Henri Menke. You can also use `\noexpand` for neutralizing the circumstance that TeX takes ends of files for something that is similar to outer tokens. You might be interested in the discussion [How does TeX handle EOF which took place in the usenet-newsgroup comp.text.tex in March 2008](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.text.tex/hUORp2VKRn0/w_CNeQCheFAJ).

Comment: @HenriMenke You can use `\noexpand` here. But you can as well use `\relax`: `a\scantokens{b}c vs. a\scantokens{b\relax}c`. Just something that puts TeX's reading apparatus into stats S (skipping blanks) so that the endline-character which gets inserted when `\scantokens`' re-tokenization-part is carried out won't get tokenized as a space-token.  ;-)  With `\input`/`\@@input` and `\scantokens` and the like you can use `\noexpand` for neutralizing the circumstance that TeX takes ends of files for something that is similar to an `\outer`-token.

Comment: By the way: `\noexpand` generally is useful for temporarily suppressing the `\outer`-property of macros that are defined in terms of `\outer`:  `\outer\def\bar{baz}` and `\expandafter\def\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\noexpand\bar}` versus `\outer\def\bar{baz}` and `\def\foo{\bar}`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou I just found your valuable comment which provides the link to [How to do scantokens inside edef without triggering runaway definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9826/how-to-do-scantokens-inside-edef-without-triggering-runaway-definition). I wish to apologize as I should have seen this comment earlier. The information available via that link already covers the aspect of neutralizing the "outerness" of ends of files. Thus my remark about the usage of `\noexpand` for neutralizing the outerness of ends of files is obsolete. Please pardon me for not noticing this earlier.

Comment: @UlrichDiez your comment was useful though thanks as it alerted me to the fact that Henri's issue was different, I just saw "scantokens and assumed that he was referring to the end of file token:-)