# How to input/include individual files as rows for a table?

Tags: input, tabularray

In a scenario where attempting to build multiple documents where each document will have a page with their own (long) table using common data. The following is a minimal example of the table definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{
    colspec={m{100pt}X},
    rowhead=1,
    width=\textwidth,
}
    Key & Value \\
    first & desc1 \\
    second & desc2 \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

I was hoping to use the [`\input`](https://latexref.xyz/_005cinput.html) command to define which rows a table would use, allowing a table definition in one document to use a different set of rows than another document. For example:

###### [test.tex]

```
\begin{longtblr}{
    colspec={m{100pt}X},
    rowhead=1,
    width=\textwidth,
}
    Key & Value \\
    \input{test-row1}
    \input{test-row2}
\end{longtblr}
```

###### [test-row1.tex]

```
second & desc1 \\
```

However, this approach will yield the following error:

```
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
```

Is there a way to make this work?

A current workaround is to split each column into their own include file as follows, but hoping to avoid this:

```
    \input{test-r2c1} & \input{test-r2c2} \\
```

Comment: As expected, that's how the tabularray package works.

Comment: Link to slightly-related question: [expansion - tabularray: Expand multiple macros - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617961/tabularray-expand-multiple-macros) ; [expansion - tabulararray: can't use def to set cell properties? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624063/tabulararray-cant-use-def-to-set-cell-properties)

Comment: Okay this one needs some tweak because • \input in LaTeX is not expandable, unlike \input in plain TeX, and • using \input expandably is a bit problematic as well. Anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using David Carlisle's "horrible hack" in the linked question above, we have (also read the comment in the code to understand what it does)

```
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}


\ExplSyntaxOn
% read the file content
\file_get:nnN {test-row1} {\ExplSyntaxOff} \testrowone
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{longtblr}[expand=\expandafter]{
    colspec={m{100pt}X},
    rowhead=1,
    width=\textwidth
}
    Key & Value \\
    first & desc1 \\
    \expandafter\empty\testrowone
    %\expandafter\empty\testrowtwo, etc.
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a bit ugly however, since the "read file content" part is separated from the actual include part.

Comment: Also remind me to write documentation for my other package (which is a bit applicable here) soon...

Comment: Thanks, this works great for my use case. A lot of new commands (to me) to research.

Comment: I had a similar problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611786/misplaced-noalign-because-input-before-booktabs-rule) that was a bit frustrating since `\input` rows worked fine in the past without latex3 hacks.

Comment: If you are not at the start of the project, and you handle R, consider not scatter your row data in many files but one or few databases that can be managed to extract subsets or merge data in many ways and can be showed  as LaTeX tables.  An example  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392910/11604) that show as  only some of the 32 rows and some of the 11 variables of `mtcars` data frame.

Answer (score 3):

With the latest `functional` version 2022G (2022-05-22) and `tabularray` version 2022B (2022-06-01), it is easy to input files inside tables.

There is a [new](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/81) `functional` library and outer spec `evaluate` in `tabularray` package. With this library,  you can make `tabularray` evaluate every occurrence of a specified **protected** function (which must be defined with `\prgNewFunction`) and replace it with the return value before splitting table body:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{functional}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test1.tex}
first & desc1 \\
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test2.tex}
second & desc2 \\
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}[evaluate=\fileInput]{hlines}
  Key & Value \\
  \fileInput{test1}
  \fileInput{test2}
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

In the example `\fileInput` is a predefined function in `functional` package.

[image]

In general, it is possible to generate the whole table body with a function with this library.

Comment: Not really related, but about the functional library... I think its main advantage is not "more intuitive for users", but that you can *nest unexpandable function* without clunky temporary variables.

Comment: As long as you need to use the library to do something other than as a normal programming language (e.g. passing the result of some computation into another command from another library) you need to know somewhat of how TeX expansion works etc. for now I think it would be better to explain (in the documentation) how to mix functional library with normal expl3 code.

Comment: (also when will you implement `expand` supporting multiple arguments)

Comment: @user202729 Now you can expand multiple macros by writing `evaluate=\TlUse` and putting `\TlUse` before each macro.

Comment: Actually that would only allow expanding "macro which takes no argument"... either way I guess `evaluate=Expand` with functional package should be able to do most; but it's somewhat nontrivial to come up with so would be better to include some example in documentation (or link to questions to TeX.SE?) // For the other point, in retrospect `\TlSet` can be used to transport the data to expl3, except for the limitation that the first character must be l or g; but then this is nontrivial as well (I think unless the user is already familiar with expl3 it's harded it to come up with this one).

Comment: @user202729 I will implement the multiple-expansion feature eventually. But my todo list is quite long. So I can not tell you when to do it.

Comment: @user202729 The data types are the same in both `functional` and `expl3` (only functions are different). `\TlSet` can handle macro names with any leading characters, but this is still undocumented (you may read the code if you are interested).

Comment: @user202729 It is a pity that I can not expand `\@@input` inside tabularray tables, although `\@@input` is said to be expandable.

Comment: Yes, I think you need to deal with some EOF marker (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516031/why-is-everyeof-noexpand-needed-to-avoid-file-ended-while-scanning-definitio and linked post) (didn't test however)