# Understanding scantokens

Tags: macros, e-tex, detokenize

I am trying to work with `\scantokens`, but apparently, I don't really understand it. I want to detokenize some sequence into a register `\S`:

```
\let\ea\expandafter
\newtoks\S
\ea\S\ea{\detokenize{\textbf{f}}}
```

manipulate it (omitted), and retokenize. My first attempt

```
\ea\def\ea\T\ea{\ea\scantokens\ea{\the\S}}
```

yields `\T=macro: \scantokens {\textbf {f}}.`. That's not wrong, but probably we can get the `\scantokens` out of `\T`. I thought, expanding once more should do it, but apparently not. So far, also what's written [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9826/how-to-do-scantokens-inside-edef-without-triggering-runaway-definition) about `\everyeof{\noexpand}` does not help me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\ea\expandafter
\newtoks\S
\ea\S\ea{\detokenize{\textbf{f}}}

\ea\def\ea\T\ea{\ea\scantokens\ea{\the\S}}%
\show\T %\T=macro: \scantokens {\textbf {f}}.

%Runaway definition?
%->\textbf {f}
% ! File ended while scanning definition of \R.
\ea\ea\ea\def\ea\ea\ea\R\ea\ea\ea{\T}

%Runaway definition?
%->\textbf {f} \noexpand 
%! File ended while scanning definition of \R.
\everyeof{\noexpand}%
\ea\ea\ea\def\ea\ea\ea\R\ea\ea\ea{\T}
\show\R
\everyeof{}
\begin{document}
    \R
\end{document}
```

Comment: you didn't like my answer to your previous question then? :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sure I did, but I want to understand my misconception. I'll accept your answer as soon as I find time to understand why *that* works ;). Btw., how did you guess the two are related? ():-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do the scantokens on the outside rather than inside the def:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\ea\expandafter
\newtoks\S
\S\ea{\detokenize{\textbf{f}}}


\scantokens\ea{\ea\def\ea\T\ea{\the\S}}%
\show\T %\T=macro: \textbf {f}.


\begin{document}
f \T
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `\noexpand` approach needs an `\edef` - `\scantokens` is 'tricky' (basically buggy). So something like:

```latex
\everyeof{\noexpand}%
\edef\T{\noexpand\scantokens{\noexpand\unexpanded{\detokenize{\textbf{f}}}}}
\edef\R{\T}
\show\R
\everyeof{}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\R
\end{document}
```

As you might have non-expandable content inside the rescanned tokens, I've wrapped them all in `\unexpanded`.

(I've somewhat shortened the setup to make it in my opinion clearer).

Comment: What does the `\edef` do if its content starts with a \noexpand? I guess the two `\noexpand` in the `\edef` keep `\scantokens` and `\unexpanded` as is until `\edef\R{\T}`. But what do I need the `\unexpanded` for? And why is `\detokenize` expanded already after `\edef\T`, although it occurs inside `\unexpanded`? Supposedly, because the `\unexpanded` is `\noexpand`ed? Probably this all makes sense to me. Except I don't understand why `\scantokens` did not work with `\expandafter`.

Comment: @Bubaya `\noexpand` makes a token temporarily equal to `\relax`, so in an `\edef` it does nothing but is unchanged. This is standard TeX programming. The `\unexpanded` is the as `\textbf` (or similar) are not safe in an `\edef`. I guess you could use `\protected@edef` in LaTeX, but there are still edge cases so this seemed easier: inside `\unexpanded`, no expansion occurs (it's like a toks but without assignment).

Comment: @Bubaya Like I said, `\scantokens` is essentially buggy - there are ways it works, and ways it doesn't, and you have to pick the correct approach. That's why it's regarded by many people as a bit of a risky primitive (and why LuaTeX has `\scantextokens` which fixes these issues).